# Error in Jet Nestruev, Smooth Manifolds and Observables, Proposition 9.30?

Tags: abstract-algebra, differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $A$ a commutative $R$-algebra (with units). For an $R$-algebra homomorphism $\varphi: A \to R$ let $\mu_\varphi = \ker \varphi$.
Let $T_{\varphi}^* A = \mu_{\varphi}/\mu_{\varphi}^2$ the cotangent space and $T_\varphi A$ the derivations $\xi: A \to R$ with $\xi(fg) = \varphi(g)\xi(f)+\varphi(f)\xi(g)$. Let $\rho: A \to T_{\varphi}^* A, f \mapsto [f - \varphi(f)\cdot 1_A]$. Then it is easy to show that $\rho^* : \text{Hom}(T_{\varphi}^* A,R) \to \text{Hom}(A,R), \Psi \mapsto \Psi\circ \rho$ has $\text{Im}\rho^* \subseteq T_\varphi A$. It is also not difficult to see that then $\nu_\varphi: \text{Hom}(T_{\varphi}^* A,R) \to T_\varphi A, \nu_\varphi(\Psi) = \rho^*(\Psi)$ is surjective.

I think $\nu_\varphi$ should also be injective since $\rho$ is surjective and therefore $\nu_\varphi$ be an isomorphism. But in Jet Nestruev, Smooth Manifolds and Observables, Proposition 9.30 this is only claimed for $R$ being a field. Is this an error?

The statement of the proposition is

> For any $R$-algebra $A$, the natural surjection of $R$-modules $\nu_\varphi: \text{Hom} (T_{\varphi}^* A,R) \to T_\varphi A$ is defined. If $R$ is a field, then $\nu_\varphi$ is an isomorphism.